# gcc, compiling, and NO_GLIBC is false

Tags: c++, gcc

I want to compile something on Windows. There are a few lines:

```
#ifdef NO_GLIBC
#include "getopt/getopt.h"
#else
#include "sys/utsname.h"
#endif
```

then it fails, saying "utsname.h" is missing. Thats right, since its not a Windows thing. So somehow I have to make NO_GLIBC true, how to do this?

EDIT: Ive never programmed in C, Im a Php, Delphi expert

Comment: You don't have to make it true, you just have to define it. `#ifdef` = "if defined".

Comment: The question is, do you have `"getopt/getopt.h"`? Otherwise you might need another level of conditional compilation around the code you have.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg  I do have that file

Comment: @davmac yea thats right but then other errors come up :)

Comment: @JohnSmith as it stands your question is purely about the definition of the NO_GLIBC macro. As far as I can see that has now been resolved. Even if you still can't compile, your question has been answered. If you have other problems that you can't resolve yourself, you can always ask further questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the NO_GLIBC macro with the -D flag given to gcc, e.g.

```
gcc -DNO_GLIBC=1 -c foo.c -o foo.o
```